# Maui with Microsoft.Graph won't release build

Tags: nuget, maui

I am building a Maui app that will use Microsoft.Graph, but when I try to build a release, visual studio 2022 gets stuck in the build process.

[Build process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x4Cy.png)

But as soon as I remove Microsoft.Graph it works again.

Am using Maui 6.0
The issue can be reproduced in an empty maui project.

I have tried these versions of Microsoft.Graph: 5.0.0-rc4, 5.0.0-preview.12, 4.52.0

Rebuilding, cleaning, deleting older debug and release folders,
but nothing works.

Comment: Is there any error log about this problem?

Comment: No it just loops in the build process..

Comment: You can try to update your `nugets` of your app to the latest version and try again.